# When I create a new custom post type, it replaces the old post type

Tags: php, plugin-development

I have created a plugin that will create a custom post type. When I create a custom post type, it replace the old one.

```
<?php
/*

*/
$new_input = array();

class CustomPostComparison
{
    /**
     * Holds the values to be used in the fields callbacks
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * Start up
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_plugin_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array($this, 'custom_post_type_register'));

    }
    public function custom_post_type_register()
    {
        $cpts = get_option('my_option_name');
        //print_r($cpts);
        //echo $cpts['supports'];exit;
        if( !empty( $cpts ) ){            

            $labels = array(
                'name'                  => _x( $cpts['post_type'], 'Post Type General Name' ),
                'singular_name'         => _x( $cpts['singular_label'], 'Post Type Singular Name'),
                'menu_name'             => $cpts['menu_name'] ? $cpts['menu_name'] : $cpts['plural_label'],
                'name_admin_bar'        => __( $cpts['post_type'], 'text_domain' ),
                'archives'              => __( $cpts['archives'], 'text_domain' ),
                'parent_item_colon'     => __( $cpts['parent_item_colon'], 'text_domain' ),
                'all_items'             => __( $cpts['all_items'] ? $cpts['all_items'] : "All ".$cpts['plural_label'] ),
                'add_new_item'          => __( $cpts['add_new_item'], 'text_domain' ),
                'add_new'               => _x( $cpts['add_new'] ? $cpts['add_new'] : 'Add New', strtolower( $cpts['singular_label'] ) ),
                'new_item'              => __( $cpts['new_item'], 'text_domain' ),
                'edit_item'             => __( $cpts['edit_item'], 'text_domain' ),
                'view_items'            => __( !empty( $cpts['view_item'] ) ? $cpts['view_item'] : "View ".$cpts['singular_label'] ),
                'search_items'          => __( $cpts['search_items'], 'text_domain' ),
                'not_found'             => __( $cpts['not_found'], 'text_domain' ),
                'not_found_in_trash'    => __( $cpts['not_found_in_trash'], 'text_domain' ),
                'featured_image'        => __( $cpts['featured_image'], 'text_domain' ),
                'set_featured_image'    => __( $cpts['set_featured_image'], 'text_domain' ),
                'remove_featured_image' => __( $cpts['remove_featured_image'], 'text_domain' ),
                'use_featured_image'    => __( $cpts['use_featured_image'], 'text_domain' ),
                'insert_into_item'      => __( $cpts['insert_into_item'], 'text_domain' ),
                'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( $cpts['uploaded_to_this_item'], 'text_domain' ),
                'items_list'            => __( $cpts['items_list'], 'text_domain' ),
                'items_list_navigation' => __( $cpts['items_list_navigation'], 'text_domain' ),
                'filter_items_list'     => __( $cpts['filter_items_list'], 'text_domain' ),
            );
            $args = array(
                'label'                 => __( $cpts['post_type'], 'text_domain' ),
                'description'           => __( $cpts['post_description'], 'text_domain' ),
                'labels'                => $labels,
                'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
                'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
                'hierarchical'          => $cpts['hierarchical'] == 'false' ? false : true,
                'public'                => $cpts['public'] == 'false' ? false : true,
                'show_ui'               => $cpts['show_ui'] == 'false' ? false : true,
                'show_in_menu'          => $cpts['show_in_menu'] == 'false' ? false : true,
                'menu_position'         => __( $cpts['menu_position'], 'text_domain' ),
                'has_archive'           => $cpts['has_archive'] == 'false' ? false : true,
                'capability_type'       => 'post',
                'show_in_rest_api'      => !empty($cpts['show_in_rest_api']) ? $cpts['show_in_rest_api'] : false,
            );
            if ( post_type_exists( $cpts['post_type'] ) ) {
                echo 'The post type is already exist';
            }
            else{
                register_post_type( $cpts['post_type'],$args);
            }           


        }
    }

    /**
     * Add options page
     */
    public function add_plugin_page()
    {
        // This page will be under "Settings"
        add_options_page(
            'Settings Admin', 
            'Post Type Creater', 
            'manage_options', 
            'my-setting-admin', 
            array( $this, 'create_admin_page' )
        );
    }
    /**
     * Options page callback
     */
    public function create_admin_page()
    {
        // Set class property
        $this->options = get_option( 'my_option_name' );
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">

            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php settings_fields( 'my_option_group' ); ?>
                <?php do_settings_sections( 'my_option_group' ); ?>
                <table border="0" grid-column-gap: 100px>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">
                            Custom Post Type Creater
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Post Type:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[post_type]" id="custom_post_type" required="required"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Description:</td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="my_option_name[post_description]" id="custom_post_desc"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Singular Label:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[singular_label]" id="singular_label" required="required"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Plural Label:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[plural_label]" id="plural_label" required="required"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hierarchical:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="my_option_name[hierarchical]" id="hierarchical">
                                <option value="false" selected="selected">false</option>
                                <option value="true">true</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Has Archive:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="my_option_name[has_archive]" id="has_archive">
                                <option value="false" >false</option>
                                <option value="true" selected="selected">true</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">Supports:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[supports]" id="supports_title" value="title" checked="checked">Title<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[supports]" id="supports_editor" value="editor" checked="checked">Editor<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[supports]" id="supports_author" value="author">Author<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[supports]" id="supports_thumbnail" value="thumbnail">Thumbnail<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[supports]" id="supports_excerpt" value="excerpt">Excerpt<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[supports]" id="supports_trackbacks" value="trackbacks">Trackbacks<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[supports]" id="supports_custom-fields" value="custom-fields">Custom-fields<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[supports]" id="supports_comments" value="comments">Comments<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[supports]" id="supports_revisions" value="revisions">Revisions<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[supports]" id="supports_page-attributes" value="page-attributes">Page-attributes<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[supports]" id="supports_post-formats" value="post-formats">Post-formats<br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Add New:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[add_new]" id="add_new"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Add New Item:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[add_new_item]" id="add_new_item"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Edit Item:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[edit_item]" id="edit_item"></td>
                    </tr>           
                    <tr>
                        <td>New Item:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[new_item]" id="new_item"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>All Items:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[all_items]" id="all_items"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>View Items:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[view_items]" id="view_items"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Search Items:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[search_items]" id="search_items"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Not Found:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[not_found]" id="not_found"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Not Found In Trash:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[not_found_in_trash]" id="not_found_in_trash"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Parent Item Colon:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[parent_item_colon]" id="parent_item_colon"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Menu Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[menu_name]" id="menu_name"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Featured Image:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[featured_image]" id="featured_image"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Set Featured Image:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[set_featured_image]" id="set_featured_image"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Remove Featured Image:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[remove_featured_image]" id="remove_featured_image"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Use Featured Image:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[use_featured_image]" id="use_featured_image"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Archives:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[archives]" id="archives"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Insert Into Item:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[insert_into_item]" id="insert_into_item"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Uploaded to this Item:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[uploaded_to_this_item]" id="uploaded_to_this_item"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Filter Items List:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[filter_items_list]" id="filter_items_list"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Items List Navigation:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[items_list_navigation]" id="items_list_navigation"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Items List:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[items_list]" id="items_list"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Public:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="my_option_name[public]" id="public">
                                <option value="false">false</option>
                                <option value="true" selected="selected">true</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Show UI:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="my_option_name[show_ui]" id="show_ui">
                                <option value="false">false</option>
                                <option value="true" selected="selected">true</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Show In Nav Menus:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="my_option_name[show_in_nav_menus]" id="show_in_nav_menus">
                                <option value="false">false</option>
                                <option value="true" selected="selected">true</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Show In Menu:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="my_option_name[show_in_menu]" id="show_in_menu">
                                <option value="false">false</option>
                                <option value="true" selected="selected">true</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Menu Position:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[menu_position]" id="menu_position"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Menu Icon:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[menu_icon]" id="menu_icon"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Capability Type:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[capability_type]" value="post" id="capability_type"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">Taxonomies:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[taxonomies]" id="taxonomies_category" value="category">Category<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[taxonomies]" id="taxonomies_post_tag" value="post_tag">Post_tag<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[taxonomies]" id="taxonomies_product_cat" value="product_cat">Product_Cat<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[taxonomies]" id="taxonomies_product_tag" value="product_tag">Product_tag<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="my_option_name[taxonomies]" id="taxonomies_product_shipping_class" value="product_shipping_class">Product_Shipping_Class<br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rewrite:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="my_option_name[rewrite]" id="rewrite">
                                <option value="false">false</option>
                                <option value="true" selected="selected">true</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>With Front:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="my_option_name[with_front]" id="with_front">
                                <option value="false">false</option>
                                <option value="true" selected="selected">true</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rewrite Slug:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="my_option_name[rewrite_slug]" id="rewrite_slug"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Show In REST API:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="my_option_name[show_in_rest_api]" id="show_in_rest_api">
                                <option value="false" selected="selected">false</option>
                                <option value="true">true</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">
                            <?php submit_button($name = 'Submit'); ?>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    public function page_init()
    {        
        register_setting(
            'my_option_group', // Option group
            'my_option_name', // Option name
            array( $this, 'sanitize' ) // Sanitize
        );
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize each setting field as needed
     *
     * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
     */
    public function sanitize( $input )
    {
        $new_input = array();
        //echo $input['post_type'];exit;
        $field = array('post_type', 'post_description','singular_label','plural_label','hierarchical','hierarchical','has_archive','supports','add_new','add_new_item','edit_item','new_item','all_items','view_items','search_items','not_found','not_found_in_trash','parent_item_colon','menu_name','featured_image','set_featured_image','remove_featured_image','use_featured_image','archives','insert_into_item','uploaded_to_this_item','filter_items_list','items_list_navigation','items_list','public','show_ui','show_in_nav_menus','show_in_menu','menu_position','menu_icon','capability_type','taxonomies','rewrite','with_front','rewrite_slug','show_in_rest_api');

        foreach ($field as $value) {

            if( isset( $input[$value] ) ){
                $new_input[$value] = sanitize_text_field( $input[$value] );
            }
        }
        return $new_input;

    }
}
$my_settings_page = new CustomPostComparison();
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it? That's what your code appears to be written to do. Keep in mind that `register_post_type()` needs to be run on every page load. It's not something you run one and it permanently registers the post type.

Comment: Hi,tell me the changes i can do to resolve the problem.Thanks